# The form file does not contain valid XML.Form cannot be opened.Contents is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

[image: screenshot]

I'm using NetBeans IDE, I'm creating a JFrame and during work on my project the computer shut down. When I run it again and run NetBeans and enter to my project design mode, it pops up this message. So how to fix the XML file for the JFrame form?

> The form file does not contain valid XML.Form cannot be opened.Contents is not allowed in prolog

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An image is not very helpful; please tell us what you're trying to do, how to reproduce this error. Use the "edit" link below your post to edit this into your question. Good luck!

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm edit discrption

Comment: Ok, I've edited it a bit further (you can roll it back if you disagree: click on the "edited .... ago" link to go to the edit history). You meant a JFrame when you said "jfarm", right?

Comment: Also - Prolog is a programming language. It seems that for some reason, your IDE thinks it's a Prolog program instead of a Java program.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm using java language , not prolog , but this massage pop to me in netbeans IDE design mode , Jframe not jfarm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Swing GUI forms, NetBeans keeps a `.form` XML file in the same folder as the `.java` source file.  The contents of this `.form` file is used to generate the `.java` code within the 'Generated Code' sections of your `JFrame`.

It looks like this `.form` file became corrupt when your computer shut down.

It's difficult to say much more without seeing the contents of this file.  Try finding this `.form` file and opening it in a text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: im found file .form and open it by notepad++ but it just contiant NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL .....................

Comment: @user3905775: OK, looks like the contents of this file have been lost.  Sorry to hear that.  I'm afraid I don't know of any way to recreate this file from the Java code it was used to generate.